# Deriving form of differential wave equation from $\nabla^2 \psi = \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial{r}^2}(r \psi)$

Tags: spherical-coordinates, wave-equation, laplacian

I am currently studying *Optics*, fifth edition, by Hecht. In chapter **2.9 Spherical Waves**, when discussing the spherical coordinates $x = r \sin(\theta) \sin(\phi)$, $y = r \sin(\theta)\sin(\phi)$, $z = r \cos(\theta)$, the author says that the Laplacian operator is

$$\nabla^2 = \dfrac{1}{r^2} \dfrac{\partial}{\partial{r}} \left( r^2 \dfrac{\partial}{\partial{r}} \right) + \dfrac{1}{r^2 \sin(\theta)} \dfrac{\partial}{\partial{\theta}} \left( \sin(\theta) \dfrac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \right) + \dfrac{1}{r^2 \sin^2 \theta} \dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial \phi^2}. \tag{2.67}$$

The author then continues as follows:

> We can obtain this result without being familiar with Eq. (2.67). Start with the Cartesian form of the Laplacian, Eq. (2.61); operate on the spherically symmetrical wavefunction $\psi(r)$; and convert each term to polar coordinates. Examining only the $x$-dependence, we have
> $$\dfrac{\partial{\psi}}{\partial{x}} = \dfrac{\partial{\psi}}{\partial{r}} \dfrac{\partial{r}}{\partial{x}}$$
> and
> $$\dfrac{\partial^2{\psi}}{\partial{x}^2} = \dfrac{\partial^2{\psi}}{\partial{r^2}} \left( \dfrac{\partial{r}}{\partial{x}} \right)^2 + \dfrac{\partial{\psi}}{\partial{r}} \dfrac{\partial^2{\psi}}{\partial{x}^2}$$
> since
> $$\psi(\vec{\mathbf{r}}) = \psi(r)$$
> Using
> $$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = r^2$$
> we have
> $$\dfrac{\partial{r}}{\partial{x}} = \dfrac{x}{r}$$
> $$\dfrac{\partial^2{r}}{\partial{x}^2} = \dfrac{1}{r} \dfrac{\partial}{\partial{x}}x + x \dfrac{\partial}{\partial{x}} \left( \dfrac{1}{r} \right) = \dfrac{1}{r} \left( 1 - \dfrac{x^2}{r^2} \right)$$
> and so
> $$\dfrac{\partial^2{\psi}}{\partial{x}^2} = \dfrac{x^2}{r^2} \dfrac{\partial^2{\psi}}{\partial{r}^2} + \dfrac{1}{r} \left( 1 - \dfrac{x^2}{r^2} \right) \dfrac{\partial{\psi}}{\partial{r}}$$
> Now having $\partial^2{\psi}/\partial{x}^2$, we form $\partial^2{\psi}/\partial{y}^2$ and $\partial^2{\psi}/\partial{z}^2$, and on adding get
> $$\nabla^2 \psi(r) = \dfrac{\partial^2{\psi}}{\partial{r}^2} + \dfrac{2}{r} \dfrac{\partial{\psi}}{\partial{r}}$$
> which is equivalent to Eq. (2.68). This result can be expressed in a slightly different form:
> $$\nabla^2 \psi = \dfrac{1}{r} \dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial{r}^2}(r \psi) \tag {2.69}$$
> The differential wave equation can then be written as
> $$\dfrac{1}{r} \dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial{r}^2}(r \psi) = \dfrac{1}{v^2} \dfrac{\partial^2{\psi}}{\partial{t}^2} \tag{2.70}$$
> Multiplying both sides by $r$ yields
> $$\dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial{r}^2}(r \psi) = \dfrac{1}{v^2} \dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial{t}^2}(r \psi) \tag{2.71}$$
> Notice that this expression is now just the one-dimensional differential wave equation, Eq. (2.11), where the space variable is $r$ and the wavefunction is the product $(r \psi)$. The solution of Eq. (2.71) is then simply
> $$r\psi(r, t) = f(r - vt)$$
> or $$\psi(r, t) = \dfrac{f(r - vt)}{r} \tag{2.72}$$
> This represents a spherical wave progressing radially outward from the origin, at a constant speed $v$, and having an arbitrary functional form $f$.

Equation 2.61 is

$$\nabla^2 \equiv \dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial{x}^2} + \dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial{y}^2} + \dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial{z}^2} \tag{2.61}$$

Equation 2.68 is

$$\nabla^2 \psi(r) = \dfrac{1}{r^2} \dfrac{\partial}{\partial{r}} \left( r^2 \dfrac{\partial{\psi}}{\partial{r}} \right) \tag{2.68}$$

It seems that the author is attempting to connect the Laplacian with the differential wave equation. But how did the author get 2.70 from 2.69? I would greatly appreciate it if people would please take the time to clarify this.

Comment: What is $v$ in equation 2.70?

Comment: @JackyChong $v$ is the velocity of the wave.

Comment: So it is constant?

Comment: @JackyChong Yes, I think so.

Comment: Nice to see you again! This must be a tough book :D

Comment: @K.defaoite haha, yes, sometimes the author is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wave equation is
$$\nabla^2 A=\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2 A}{\partial t^2}$$
The author uses the letter $v$ instead of the letter $c$ and simply plugs in our expression for $\nabla^2 \psi$ in equation 2.69 into the wave equation to reach
$$\nabla^2 \psi=\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial r^2}(r\psi)=\frac{1}{v^2}\frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial t^2}.$$
Equation 2.70.

Comment: Thanks again for the answer! Hmm, so if I'm interpreting you correctly, you're saying that the author is just pattern matching rather than deriving 2.70 from 2.69?

Comment: Basically, yeah. There's obviously a lot of assumptions at play here - no $\theta$ or $\phi$ dependency and so on. But if we have reason to believe something obeys the wave equation, and we have an expression for it's Laplacian, then it doesn't seem unreasonable to simply plug that expression into the wave equation.

Comment: Hmm, ok, I see. Thanks again for the answer. By the way, I still have your other answer open (the derivation of the Laplacian), and I intend to go through it carefully for myself once I finish this section of the textbook (soon).

Comment: Awesome! For a fuller explanation, please check out the links I provided (especially for the application of the divergence thm to curvilinear coords.)